# Show that Hicksian Demand price elasticities satisfy a given equation (Use Shephard's Lemma)

Tags: microeconomics

I got a homework exercise that I am stuck with: Use Shephard's lemma to show that price elasticities of Hicksian Demand $\varepsilon_{jk}^{h}=\frac{\partial x_{j}^{h}}{\partial p_{k}} \frac{p_{k}}{x_{j}^{h}}$ satisfy the equation: $\varepsilon_{jj}^{h}\varepsilon_{kk}^{h}\geq \varepsilon_{jk}^{h}\varepsilon_{kj}^{h}$ .

I've spent nearly 3 hours of honest work (the result is not impressive, but it was honest work) and found the following:

The Shephard's Lemma: $x^{_{k}^{h}}(\mathbf{p},U)=\frac{\partial e(\mathbf{p},U])}{\partial p_{k}}$

Cross-price elasticity: $\epsilon_{kj} = \frac{\partial x_k}{\partial p_j}\frac{p_j}{x_k}$

The symmetry of Hicksian Demand (Jehle & Reny p. 62): $\frac{\partial x_{k}^{h}(\mathbf{p},y)}{\partial p_j}=\frac{\partial x_{j}^{h}(\mathbf{p},y)}{\partial p_k}$ .

This is all I could find on this topic. Maybe if not the for whole solution I could ask for a hint on how to take the next step. I understand that to use Shephard's Lemma I should somehow obtain the expenditure function e(p, U). But how to do it is beyond me.

My interpretation of the required answer is to show that the own-price elasticity of goods *i* and *j* i greater than their cross-price elasticity (*ij* which is symmetrical to *ji*).

Comment: Hi, we have rule here that homework/self-study questions are only allowed if author shows their honest attempt at trying solve the problem himself/herself. Please add your attempt to the question

Comment: @1muflon1 Thank you - I didn't know that. I will do my best and then post it here.

Comment: You could use the fact that a Hicksian demand system has a nsd Hessian matrix...